# Entity - what type are two join tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to bring the data from two join tables. What type will be the dataset? Do I need to create a class that contains the properties from these two tables to use for the dataset type or I can use the types from the Entity mode. How can I modify my method to work properly?

```
public static IEnumerable<Result> GetCarrier()
{
    IEnumerable <Result> result = new IEnumerable<>();
    try
    {
        using (MyEntities myEntity = new MyEntities())
        {
            var result = from s in Carriers car
                     CoreEnt ent ON car.CoreEntID equals ent.CoreEntID
                     where car.NeedsTransfer == True
                     select s;
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entities aren't tables. They don't have joins, they have relations. If you have to write a join statement instead of writing `Car.Cores` you are missing relations from your context

Comment: This not C# thought! `IEnumerable <Result> result = new IEnumerable<>();`

Comment: It is also very strange that your NeedsTransfer column is of type varchar or nvarchar. It probably should be bit column, so your table will be smaller, faster and easier to work with. Because right know if you want to query this table you must type 'True' what if there will be 'true'(small letters) instead.

Comment: The class Carriers should have all members that are represented as joined table in your database. You dont need to join stuff yourself like you do in SQL, it depends how your Context in configured and it will either automatically load those "joined" tables if you Access the members or you have to say to .Include("JoinedTable") manually to load them. Maybe read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Have you even try putting a break point and look at the entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linq query can be as follows.

```
try
    {

        using (MyEntities myEntity = new MyEntities())
        {
            var result = (from s in Carriers
                         join ent in CoreEnt on s.CoreEntID equals ent.CoreEntID                       
                         where s.NeedsTransfer == True
                         select s).Single(); 
            //using Single()/FirstOrDefault() depends on what is the type of other objects. If it shows error to you than you can remove it
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return result;
    }
```